# Where can I setup scrolling speed in Ubuntu 13.04?

Tags: mouse, mouse-scroll, mouse-wheel

I cannot find where I can setup mouse-wheel scroll speed in Ubuntu. It's not available in mouse settings for me.

Could you give me some hint where to find it?

Right now the scrolling is very rough in big "steps" not smooth at all.

**The scrolling of mouse wheel is incredible fast** and I am unable to slow it down.

It's present in system and browsers as well.

Comment: @RaduRădeanu ;) I have the exactly opposite problem as you offer in the question in the duplicate. Please, remove the duplicate sign, if possible. Thank you. I have set everything to slowest, but the scroll is still incredible fast.

Comment: @RaduRădeanu please, could you remove the sign of `possible duplicate` I have a different problem then in the question you are offering.

Answer (score 2):

If you are using a wireless mouse (specifically a Microsoft one?), a quick and easy work around for insane scrolling speeds which may work is to simply unplug and the reinsert the USB transceiver.   It worked for me at least.  The mouse wheel now scrolls 3 lines rather than 3 pages.

According to the bug logs, the problem is actually a driver issue.  An actual fix seems in the works, but naturally isn't available in older versions.